# High voltage DC offset servo

Tags: operational-amplifier, dc, high-voltage, servo, offset

I'm working on a project and I need some assistance.

I have an audio tube amplifier output stage that I need to have adjustable operating points while maintaining a DC null at the output.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
As you can see it's a white cathode follower with a DC offset servo to null the output.
I need to be able to adjust the load line but if I adjust the operating point I must also adjust the servo offset.

R12 is the variable resistor to set the CVS voltage but in order to maintain 0vDC on the output of the amplifier and keep the current of the tubes balanced I need to decrease the negative supply voltage of the servo when I increase the resistance of R12 and I need to increase the supply voltage of the servo when I decrease the resistance of R12, up to -300v.
Sadly opamps with the required supply voltage and output swing don't exist unless you want to pay $500

So I have 2 problems, I need to have some sort of servo that will adjust the supply voltage of the DC offset servo as I change the resistance of R12 and I need to figure out an alternative way to an opamp for use as a DC offset servo since no opamp worth paying for is going to handle the needed voltages.

Comment: Tubes have quite a good swing! Can you use another one to boost the output of your op-amp up to the required voltage, at least for the -ve rail adjust?

Comment: Tubes can't output a negative voltage and the min/max swing range needs to be pretty much +15v (or more) to -150v.

Comment: if you say so. Are you thinking outside the box enough? Don't forget I said boost the voltage *up*, to provide the -ve rail!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The output voltages of a tube can only be positive and positive voltages on the grid bias or -ve will obviously not work. In order to produce -150v on the output of the opamp I need a negative supply of -300v to the opamp, which will kill it.

Comment: I mean the opamp and the tube grid/cathode at the PSU -ve rail, the tube anode providing the -ve rail, or at least the -150 to +15v, to where it's needed. Obviously you would have to level shift control signals down to the opamp if they came from a groundy area, locally regulate your amp +ve supply to PSU -ve +25v. Perhaps grid to PSU -ve and cathode follow the output of the opamp?

Comment: I don't see the point in this configuration. I'm not sure how you intend to get the -150v on the cathode/grid to begin with as the opamp cannot supply it. Sure the anode of a tube can output -150v if you apply -150v to it's cathode and grid but there would be no point and probably horrible linearity.

Comment: You presumably have a power supply with a -ve rail???

Comment: Yeah of course, the opamp wouldn't function without it. I use the opa445ap opamp to function as the DC offset servo but it limits the maximum supply voltages at +/- 45v. You cannot buy an opamp with my needed 300v supply voltages for anything less than hundreds of dollars. Hence my problem, one of them at least.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I meant cascode, not follower. The opamp would live and work within 25v of the PSU -ve rail, of course you cannot get a 300v opamp. The tube, or a 1000v MOSFET for that matter, would then take the 25v range output of the opamp and translate that up to the +15 to -150v needed.

Comment: That makes much more sense, you were confusing me there for a minute. There's no way a tube can do that, they only work with positive voltages. As for a mosfet, I suppose a 5x gain could work but I don't know how it would handle the voltages flowing over into positive and my understanding of transistors sucks so I'm not sure I know how to set that up.

Comment: I knew nothing about electronics 3 months ago. I still have much to learn about mosfets. I'm afraid I will need an example circuit as to how this is done. I understand that unlike tubes, mosfets are terrible voltage amplifiers and will need some sort of negative feed back to linearize them. I would need to figure out how to get the 5x gain I need which  I'm sort of clueless on and as far as I know, a P type mosfet doesn't amplify positive voltages so a swing into the positive range would be unlinear I'm assuming?

Comment: Then again there will be no current flowing into or out of the grid bias, can a mosfet even function on no current?

Comment: What device are you driving that needs +15v to -150v?

Comment: As the schematic shows, It's driving the grid of the triode. The tube configuration is a white cathode follower, a type of push pull output stage. In order to get 0VDC on the output of the WCF I need the DCoffset servo to bias the grid of the top triode. The only time there is 0VDC on the output is when both tubes are running as the exact same impedance so the DC offset servo takes its input from the output of the WCF and then tries to balance the current conduction of the top triode to equal the bottom triode so its inverting input matches its non-inverting input which is attached to ground.

Comment: Actually the current conduction is not an issue because I can just have the mosfet going into ground and use it as a Vreference but there's still the issue of positive voltage swings. Mosfets can't linearly amplify both positive and negative voltages right?

Comment: Getting confused. So the +15V to -150V is actually on the grid, not the anode/cathode? Still I want to know, what device is the amp driving? You show a 300 Ohm resistor to ground, is this the load? What peak-to-peak output voltage do you expect to get? BTW your schematic seems to have disappeared.

Comment: +15v to -150v is the grid bias voltage and voltage swing depending on where on the load line I have the tubes operating and how much I amplify the signal. The amp will drive headphones or speakers, the peak to peak voltage will be variable. This circuit is a small portion of a grander design, best not to try to understand it at face value. Right now I just need to focus on getting my opamp to output -150v.

Comment: I need a linear gain of 5 of what the opamp outputs, how do I go about doing this?